# Ansible files lookup in directory remote hosts

Tags: ansible

I am trying to execute the scripts from a directory in a particular order with an interval of 90 sec each iteration. For instance, I want to to start the scripts under /opt/scripts/, and it has (SK-1.sh, SK-2.sh, PX.sh, N1.sh,N2.sh). I want to start scripts that are *SK* and then *PX* and finally *N*.

```
- name: execute scripts A
shell: "ls -ltr {{ item }}"
args:
  chdir: "/opt/scripts/"
with_fileglob:
- "/opt/scripts/*SK*.sh"
- "/opt/scripts/*PX*.sh"
- "/opt/scripts/*N*.sh"
loop_control:
  pause: 90
```

But fileglob will look up for those scripts only on the controller host (Ansible tower),
hence not working.  Is there some kind of filter I can use that would work on remote hosts rather controller host ?

I am trying to avoid the listing of the files from a previous task and register the items to process.
After all that is becoming a two step task.

Comment: The **Notes** section of the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html) *does suggest* using the `find` module for remote systems.

Comment: It is not only `fileglob`but all other `lookups` that get executed only on the controller. To get a file list from the target, you will have to use `find` or a shell command in a previous task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*Start scripts that are SK and then PX and finally N.*"**

A: The Ansible module [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-builtin-find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) neither keeps the order of the patterns nor sorts the results. You'll have to iterate the list of the globs on your own and sort the results to achieve the required order. For example, create a file with the tasks

```yaml
shell> cat find_and_execute.yml
- find:
    paths: /tmp
    patterns: "{{ eitem }}"
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ '%H:%M:%S'|strftime }} Execute {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list|sort }}"
  loop_control:
    pause: 3
```

and use it in a playbook. For example

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: find_and_execute.yml
      loop:
        - 'SK*.sh'
        - 'PX*.sh'
        - 'N*.sh'
      loop_control:
        loop_var: eitem
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 18:19:14 Execute /tmp/SK-1.sh
  msg: 18:19:17 Execute /tmp/SK-2.sh
  msg: 18:19:21 Execute /tmp/PX.sh
  msg: 18:19:24 Execute /tmp/N1.sh
  msg: 18:19:27 Execute /tmp/N2.sh
```

Fit the parameters to your needs.

---

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: /tmp
        patterns:
          - 'SK*.sh'
          - 'PX*.sh'
          - 'N*.sh'
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg:
  - /tmp/SK-2.sh
  - /tmp/SK-1.sh
  - /tmp/N2.sh
  - /tmp/N1.sh
  - /tmp/PX.sh
```